# EF5/Modify-Error: ApplyChanges is not a member of

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I want to use STE in my VS2010/.NET 4/VB.NET Client-Server Application.

I find some helpfull links, but with EF 4.5 I cannot use the "ApplyChanges"-Method. They is created with the context.tt - but not able to use.

My architecture is client-server and the parts of the entity are in different assemblies. I can delete and Add new entries - but I´m not able to modify a existing on.

What can be the reason?

Comment: If you are using VS2010 you cannot use EF 4.5 or EF 5 because they are dependent on .NET 4.5 which is not supported in VS2010. How exactly did you create STEs?